# I am new on Android so i search a lot but not solve this error Could not find intellij-core.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    **https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar**

Comment: can you show your logcat?

Comment: Logcat image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBXYd.png

Answer (score 0):

Add maven to your poject.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" };
    }
}
```